# How to increase DoubleAnimation by 1?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to increase the slider value 0 to 100 during an animation. It increases by fraction, Since Slider.Value is Double, I couldnt use Int32Animation. How do I increase the slider value by 1?

```
<Slider Height="23" Name="slider1" Width="100" SmallChange="1"  IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="100" />

 <DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="slider1" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
    From="1" To="100" Duration="0:0:10" />
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you try to rephrase it?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `By` property without `From` or `To`:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="slider1"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
    By="1"
    Duration="0:0:10"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately 'By' does not do what you would expect it to. This answer would cause the animation to go to a value of 1 over 10 seconds.